# Display an element on svg image at a relative position

Tags: javascript, css, svg, position

In my HTML, there is a SVG image which is supposedly representing a basketball court. The idea is to click at any spot to record scored and missed shots.

The court looks good, I managed to capture the click and its positions. What I fail to do is to display the context menu and the scored/missed image at the given position. The menu and the result image are displayed at the bottom of the page.

I guess it's all a matter of CSS and displaying those 2 elements on top of the SVG, could you help me to do so?

Here is what I come up with so far: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KGGwpJ

---

Edit 2: it seems to work fine when I add "px" after the "top" and "left" attributes. The issue I now have is to keep the image at the right position when the svg is resized... or not to resize the svg.

---

Edit: Adding the code in the post

```js
var pos_x = 0;
var pos_y = 0;

function shot_taken(zone, x, y) {
  pos_x = x;
  pos_y = y;
  document.getElementById('context_menu').style.left = pos_x;
  document.getElementById('context_menu').style.top = pos_y;
  alert(x + " " + y);
  document.getElementById('context_menu').style.display = 'block';
}

function add_shot(is_scored) {
  if (is_scored) {
    document.getElementById('scored').style.left = (pos_x - 16);
    document.getElementById('scored').style.top = (pos_y - 16);
    document.getElementById('missed').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('scored').style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('missed').style.left = (pos_x - 15);
    document.getElementById('missed').style.top = (pos_y - 15);
    document.getElementById('scored').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('missed').style.display = 'block';
  }
  hide_submenu();
}

function hide_submenu() {
  document.getElementById('context_menu').style.display = 'none';
  hide_menu = true;
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background: #2B2B2B;
}

.court {
  fill: #7A7A7A;
  stroke: #2B2B2B;
  stroke-width: 4;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}

.zone {
  fill: #7A7A7A;
  stroke: #2B2B2B;
  stroke-width: 4;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}

.zone:hover {
  fill: #FEA400;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.shot_on_court {
  z-index: 99;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
}

.court_container {
  position: relative;
}

.onclick_menu {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 150px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 4px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: 'lucida sans unicode', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.onclick_menu {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

.onclick_menu>ul.onclick_menu_content {
  z-index: 10;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  list-style: none;
  background: #fff;
  color: #333;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 4px #999;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 4px #999;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px #999
}

.onclick_menu>ul.onclick_menu_content li {
  padding: 8px;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #ccc;
}

.onclick_menu>ul.onclick_menu_content li:hover {
  background: #EC6603;
  color: #fff;
}

.onclick_menu>ul.onclick_menu_content li:last-child {
  border: none
}
```

```html
<div class="court_container">
  <svg id="basketball" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 1280 871">
     <script>
     function clicked(zone, evt){
      var e = evt.target;
      var dim = e.getBoundingClientRect();
      var x = evt.clientX /*- dim.left*/;
      var y = evt.clientY /*- dim.top*/;
      shot_taken(zone, x, y);
     }
     </script>
    
     <rect x="25" y="31" class="court" width="1228" height="771"></rect>
     <rect x="25" y="31" class="zone" width="180" height="426" onclick="clicked('zone1',evt);"/>
     <rect x="1073" y="31" class="zone" width="180" height="426" onclick="clicked('zone1',evt);"/>
     <rect x="205" y="31" class="zone" width="234" height="250" onclick="clicked('zone1',evt);"/>
     <rect x="839" y="31" class="zone" width="234" height="250" onclick="clicked('zone1',evt);"/>
     <rect x="439" y="31" class="zone" width="200" height="250" onclick="clicked('zone1',evt);"/>
     <rect x="439" y="281" class="zone" width="200" height="250" onclick="clicked('zone1',evt);"/>
     <path class="zone" d="M439,687.6v114.5h400v-115c-61,28.4-128.9,44.3-200.5,44.3C567.3,731.5,499.7,715.8,439,687.6z" onclick="clicked('zone1',evt);"/>
     <path class="zone" d="M439,531v156.6c60.7,27.8,128.3,43.4,199.5,43.4c71.6,0,139.5-15.7,200.5-43.8V531H439z" onclick="clicked('zone1',evt);"/>
     <path class="zone" d="M205,457h0.1c0-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.3V457z" onclick="clicked('zone1',evt);"/>
     <path class="zone" d="M205,281v175.7c0,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.3C253.5,558.7,336.5,640.7,439,687.6V531v-74V281H205z" onclick="clicked('zone1',evt);"/>
     <path class="zone" d="M1073,457v-2.4c-0.4,0.8-0.8,1.6-1.2,2.4H1073z" onclick="clicked('zone1',evt);"/>
     <path class="zone" d="M839,281v176v74v156.2c102-47,184.7-128.8,232.8-230.2c0.4-0.8,0.8-1.6,1.2-2.4V281H839z" onclick="clicked('zone1',evt);"/>
     <rect x="639" y="281" class="zone" width="200" height="250" onclick="clicked('zone1',evt);"/>
     <rect x="639" y="31" class="zone" width="200" height="250" onclick="clicked('zone1',evt);"/>
    </svg>

  <img class="shot_on_court" src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/lingo/Stop.png" id="missed">
  <img class="shot_on_court" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/fatcow/32/accept.png" id="scored">
  <div tabindex="0" id="context_menu" class="onclick_menu">
    <ul class="onclick_menu_content">
      <li onclick="add_shot(true)">Scored</li>
      <li onclick="add_shot(false)">Missed</li>
      <li onclick="hide_submenu()">Cancel</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems that my code was fine except that I was missing the "px" after the "top" and "left" attributes. Does anyone know why I should write them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your code is working after adding the 'px' to `top` and `left`.  Since you're using `.style.left` and `.style.top`, you're accessing CSS properties, which means that if you're using a hard pixel value, you'll need to specify that you want them in `px`.  Without the `px` you have something like:

```
top: 100;
left: 100;
```

which the browser will not know how to interpret.

By adding the `px` you'll now have:

```
top: 100px;
left: 100px;
```

Let me know if you have any more questions :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [z-index](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) and use the top, right, bottom, left in combination with the [position](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) property to align your menu:

```
.onclick_menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

Notes from [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

- The z-index property specifies the stack order of an element.
- An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order.
- z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed).

Let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: Thank you for you answer but I don't get what is different from what I already do. The z-index is set. The position is absolute. The top and left attributes are set by javascript depending on where the click happened.